# Keras.NET Using a Model as a Layer

Tags: c#, keras, deep-learning

In Python you can use a pretrained model as a layer as shown below (source [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb))

```py
import keras

from keras.applications import VGG16

from keras import models
from keras import layers


conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

My question is simple: is there a way to do it in C#? I need to:

- convert a Keras.Applications.VGG.VGG16 instance to a Keras.Layers.BaseLayer if possible
- use another method of Sequential to add it (which doesn't exist in the documentation)

C# code below.

```cs
using Keras;
using Keras.Applications.VGG;
using Keras.Layers;
using Keras.Models;

VGG16 conv_base = new VGG16(
    weights: "imagenet",
    include_top: false,
    input_shape: (150, 150, 3)
);

Sequential model = new Sequential();

model.Add(conv_base); // obviously doesn't work
model.Add(new Flatten());
model.Add(new Dense(256, activation: "relu"));
model.Add(new Dense(1, activation: "sigmoid"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using this API modification in Sequential.cs:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// [CUSTOM] You can also add models via the .AddModel() method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The model.</param>
public void AddModel(BaseModel model)
{
    var layers = model.ToPython().GetAttr("layers");
    foreach (var layer in layers)
    {
        PyInstance.add(layer: new BaseLayer(layer as PyObject).PyInstance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hero! I'm stuck with the same situation. Hopefully your approach works for me. Thanks a lot!